# Disable URL encoding for INCLUDEPICTURE in Microsoft Word

Tags: url, ms-word, escaping, ms-office

I'd like to insert a remote image in a Word document as a template variable of the form {{.FOOBAR}}. I can do this via:

```
Insert > Quick Parts > Field
```

and then enter the field codes:

```
INCLUDEPICTURE  "{{.FOOBAR}}" \d
```

However, Word slaps on some URL escaping on the braces in the saved XML docx, killing my variable.

[image]

I've tried various options along the lines of `\{\{.FOOBAR\}\}` etc but had no luck. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Note: Yes I could just use a template variable with non-escaping characters, but {{.this}} variable format is a requirement.

Comment: See Word MVP Paul Edstein's tutorial on relative paths in fields. http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38722-word-fields-relative-paths-external-files.html

Comment: Thanks for the link Charles, but I can't find a solution on that page.

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old question, I have found a solution for a similar problem with encoded links in the MS365 desktop Word app. (This is not an option on the web app)

To "unencode" a link that you are trying to enter as a variable suck as `{{ link }}` or `{$link}` etc.  First insert the link as you normaly would, then right click the link and select "Toggle Field Codes".  You can then type unencoded text for your link between the " quotes ".[image: MS365 link dialog menu]